# How to preload a script in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, preload

I am trying to add a script in my website.

The problem is the script doesn't load the first time the page renders after a couple of refreshes it works and the iFrame it's responsible for shows up.

I tried a few different ways but nothing worked

Here is the code:

`_app.js`

```
      <Script
        src="https://boards.greenhouse.io/embed"
        onError={(e) => {
          console.error('Script failed to load', e)
        }}
      />
```

Notice that `onError` doesn't show any error either.

I also tried loading it in the component itself like but still doesn't work

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("lets go");
    <Script src="https://boards.greenhouse.io/embed" />
  }, []);
```

I gave it the `strategy` attribute and tried all the values it can have but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that the script doesn't load?

Comment: What do you mean? Its supposed to show some job openings but it doesn't on initial page load but after I refresh it works, So I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Did you check the network tab in devtools to see if it loads?

Comment: It does show up in the network tab

Comment: So the script loads correctly. The reason it doesn't work must be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page I was loading the script on was being navigated using

```
<Link href=""></Link>
```

I had to replace it with

```
<a href=""></a>
```

and it worked, hope it helps.